# How to uninstall GVIM using HKEY_?

Tags: batch-file, installation, installanywhere

I want to uninstall cream-0-43-gvim-7-3-107.exe software,I know the HKEY_ of the software .How can I know the uninstall-string value to uninstall it from command line ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic way of doing this using the registry, it depends upon how the program was installed and with which options etc.

You could directly run the unistaller by using the registry:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=2 Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query^
 "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Vim"^
 /V UninstallString') Do Start "" %%B
```

but this may not do everything you require.

I'd suggest you read the **uninstal.txt** in the program's directory to check which uninstall method you may want.